# Having trouble parsing data in python // html

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Links:

[main code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9srk.png)

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DEKb.png)

I am wondering why my second line of code is returning `None` values.
From what I understand the line `In[194]` is applying a function along the `[-1]` index, "US census", looking for `%` signs and then turning the remaining numerical value from `s[:-1]` to an integer.

I believe there is a space after the 3rd  X%. I have tried the code ... s[-1] == ('%' or '% ') ...
in effort to fix the problem but I really don't think that addresses it.

What is going wrong here for making `None`s? How to fix it and get the correctly values - 5,12,16,64,9,"None".

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that there are empty `<td>` elements in the original HTML source that you are parsing. There's a simple `if` addition to the end of your list comprehension that would remove the `None` values from your list:

```
values = [to_num(value.get_text()) for row in rows[1:] for value in row.find_all("td") if to_num(value.get_text())]
```

Alternative options exist too, like refining the find_all query (presumably Beautiful Soup?) to be more specific (e.g. do all of the `<td>` elements you care about have IDs or classes?), or perhaps you could simplify the if statement in the list comprehension.